# Print data returned in Code Behind to web page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to figure out the best way to go about printing some output data to a web page. I would like the user to upload a file and in the Code Behind (C#), I want to run a bunch of C# code to get a bunch of data from the file. I would then like to print that data to my web page in a table. Right now, my thought is to have the Code Behind to all the heavy lifting (getting all the data from the file) and then JavaScript/HTML or ASP.NET to print it all to the screen and CSS to manipulate it. Am I thinking of this the wrong way? If I'm heading down the right path, can I see a quick code snippet of a simple `string` variable in C# being printed to a web page via JavaScript?

Thanks in advance for any helpful input.

Comment: C# gives you the ability to do this by using `Response.Write(<text here>);`